# How do I reload Jquery jtable with change in URL on select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

Consider I am showing toppers of each subject from  a DB using Jtable.I have integrated this with Spring MVC.

```
$('#TableContainer').jtable({
    //title: 'Members',
    selectOnRowClick:true,
    selecting: true, //Enable selecting 
    paging: true, //Enable paging
    pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
    sorting: false, //Enable sorting
    actions: {
        listAction: myurl+'LoadMarks?subject='+subject,
    },

    fields: {
        ExamDate: {
            title: 'Exam Date',
        },
        StudentID: {
            title: 'Student',
        },
        Marks: {
            title: 'Marks Awarded',    
        }
    }
});
```

At page load I am using `$('#TableContainer').jtable('load');`

Now I need to make this dynamic by providing user a dropdown and on change of dropdown I need to reload jQuery jTable with respective columns.

If using  `$('#TableContainer').jtable('reload');` the url is getting called but I need to change `ListAction` variable (URL) and reload the page.
I need to change url and  load/reload jTable
Thanks In advance :)

Comment: If I understand correctly select value is the new url?

Comment: yes the url should be changed and an jtable needs to be reloaded

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski do you have any idea if i could change the url like this

Comment: Actually no, I don't know how to solve this, sorry.

Comment: thanks @KrzysztofJaniszewski  for the help finally found the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found the Answer

I needed to destroy the Jtable.
But,`$('#TableContainer').jtable('destroy');` does not work you can do it by.
refer [link](https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/170)
`$('#TableContainer').jtable({
});
$('#TableContainer').jtable('destroy');`

then you need load JTable